# Create SharePoint UserProfile for existing ActiveDirectory Contact

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, contacts

I have some Contacts in my Active-Directory which i need as UserProfiles in SharePoint 2013 (Standard Edition).

Any idea how to get contacts imported to UPS as profiles?

Edit: Some more background on what we want to do.

We want to build a searchable employee-directory in SharePoint. Because of license-restrictions (AD-CALs), a lot of our employees do not have an AD-UserAccount. They are currently maintained as AD-Contacts. We now want to be able to use these contacts as flexible as possible in SharePoint. So my idea was to get those contacts as UserProfiles in UPS and build a customized SearchSite to display the profiles in SharePoint and make them searchable. With UserProfiles we would also be able to be most flexible in the future. Some other requirements for the employee-directory: Ability to upload a picture for the contact and a global way to link to those contacts (like the OOTB person.aspx). We try to realize this with SharePoint standard-functionality first before considering custom-development.

Different ideas how to realize our needs are welcome :)

**Some more details for my problem in FIM:**

First step in FIM: 13 Adds. FIM gets all new Objects (1 OU, 11 Contacts, 1 User) from AD
[image: First step in FIM: 13 Adds. FIM gets all new Objects (1 OU, 11 Contacts, 1 User) from AD]

Second step im FIM: 1 Add. Only the one user gets imported to SharePoint UPS. 11 Contacts get silently ignored.
[image: Second step im FIM: 1 Add. Only the one user gets imported to SharePoint UPS. 11 Contacts get silently ignored.]

Comment: User profiles are based on Windows Accounts, contacts cannot be used. What are you trying to accomplish? Some sort of search scenario? You could create a list of the contacts and keep it in sync then present it in search.

Comment: Hi Matthew! Today we want to build a searchable list of all employees which includes AD-users and AD-contacts. We also need to be able to add additional contactinformation and a site like person.aspx to view employee's details. AD-users are already in UPS, so my idea was to get contacts there, too. We would also be most flexible to use the UPS-Profiles for any purpose in the future.

Comment: Why build a list of employees when you have User Profiles? User Profiles are kept in sync based on actual user accounts. Your list is not. The user profile automatically is linked to the Person.aspx page. Can you tell me about your contacts? You could create a list of Contacts and then include them in the search for People (tho it's a little tricky.) If you can better explain why you use contacts I can try to help with a solution.

Comment: Hey Matthew! Sorry for using the word "list" above. This caused confusion on your side. I have updated my initial post with some more details on what we want to achieve. Maybe you do have an idea how to realize this without UPS :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Profile are based on AD User Accounts (it requires a LDAP User Account). Based on your configuration I would create a process to import the contacts to a SharePoint Contact list and then configure People Search to include the User Profiles and the contact list as results. I won't lie and say it's easy, but it can be done if you are familiar enough with SharePoint Lists, Managed Properties, and SharePoint Search.